# Filter for "get_post_type_archive_link()"

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, hooks, archives

I tried to find filters or a hook to modify link returned by this function

[`get_post_type_archive_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type_archive_link)

I have gone through most of the documentation. I'm not sure it's not there or I'm not able to find it.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The filter is `post_type_archive_link`, [defined (WP 4.1.1) on line 1112 of file wp-includes/link-template.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1.1/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1112):

```
apply_filters( 'post_type_archive_link', $link, $post_type );
```

And the use:

```
add_filter( 'post_type_archive_link', function( $link, $post_type ) {

    //Do something

    return $link;

}, 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 5):

Just look at the [source of `get_post_type_archive_link()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.0/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1083):

```
return apply_filters( 'post_type_archive_link', $link, $post_type );
```

Sidenote: The function uses `home_url()`, which is a wrapper for [`get_home_url()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.0/wp-includes/link-template.php#L2437), which offers another filter:

```
return apply_filters( 'home_url', $url, $path, $orig_scheme, $blog_id );
```

that runs earlier. With "pretty permalinks" enabled, it runs the following:

```
$link = home_url( user_trailingslashit( $struct, 'post_type_archive' ) );
```

and without:

```
$link = home_url( '?post_type=' . $post_type );
```

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to WPSE Ittikorn!

Sometimes it is the easiest to just look right at the source. There even is a link right at the bottom of the Codex page you linked:

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1.1/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1112

There you can easily see that there actually is a filter called `post_type_archive_link`

So to give you an example:

```
add_filter( "post_type_archive_link", "wpse_179209", 10, 2 );

function wpse_179209( $link, $post_type ){
    // Do whatever you want to the $link

    return $link;
}
```